# Why is Django-1.3 not finding my fixtures for a UnitTest?

Tags: django, unit-testing, fixtures

I'm trying to use my fixtures in a UnitTest.

```
AddFavoritesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):  

fixtures = ['/Users/Bryan/work/osqa/fixtures/fixture_questions.json']  

def setUp(self):  
    self.factory = RequestFactory()  

def testAdminCanFavorite(self):  
    user = User.objects.get(pk=3)   
    ...  
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)  


======================================================================  
ERROR: testAdminCanFavorite (forum.tests.tests_building_stickyness.AddFavoritesTestCase)  
----------------------------------------------------------------------  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/Users/Bryan/work/osqa/forum/tests/tests_building_stickyness.py", line 18, in testAdminCanFavorite  
    user = User.objects.get(pk=3) # Kallie has admin  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/manager.py", line 132, in get  
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)  
  File "/Users/Bryan/work/osqa/forum/models/base.py", line 64, in get  
    obj = super(CachedQuerySet, self).get(*args, **kwargs)  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 349, in get  
    % self.model._meta.object_name)  
DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

It seems the fixtures are not loading.

I've been able to use the fixtures to populate the database, but for some reason the fixtures aren't being found in the tests.

The path is correct but I can't figure out what's going wrong.

```
$ ls /Users/Bryan/work/osqa/fixtures/fixture_questions.json 
/Users/Bryan/work/osqa/fixtures/fixture_questions.json
```

Running the test at a higher verbosity shows that the fixtures are not being found.
I'm running Django 1.3.

Comment: Are your tests in 'tests.py' for your application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the TestCase from `django.test`;

- Not: `import unittest`
- Not: `import django.utils.unittest`
- But: `import django.test`

Like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class test_something(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['one.json', 'two.json']
    ...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/#django.test.TestCase

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass the full path to the fixture, just the fixture name:

```
fixtures = ['fixture_questions.json']
```

As long as the fixture is in a `fixtures` directory within an app that's in INSTALLED_APPS, Django will find it.

Comment: I moved the fixtures into the app directory and it's still not being found. I tried to run pdb.set_trace() in the setup() and I don't see where the fixtures are loaded.

Comment: What does that have to do with my answer? Did you try what I suggested?